# linspace that would always include the final point?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For arbitrary pair of 2D points in the plane, I want to break the connecting vector to parts specified by a precision factor. However I want it to always include the start and endpoint. As an extra feature I am expecting the segmenting from the end of the vector to the beginning would give me the same segmentation from the beginning to end(of course after a flipping) . As I can see, `numpy.linspace` naturally satisfies this condition except for the situations where 
the precision is too big that it only consists of one point. Is there any built-in function to take care of this situation or any hints that I would be able to correct this behaviour?

```
import numpy as np
alpha = np.array([0,0])
beta = np.array([1,1])
alpha_beta_dist = np.linalg.norm(beta - alpha)
for i in range(10):
    precision = np.random.random(1)
    traversal = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, num = alpha_beta_dist / float(precision))
    traversal2 = np.fliplr([np.linspace(1.0, 0.0, num = alpha_beta_dist / float(precision))])
    traversal2 = traversal2[0]
    if (traversal != traversal2).all():
        print 'precision: ', precision
        print 'taversal: ', traversal
        print 'taversal2: ', traversal2[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `num` is at least 2:

```
traversal = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0,
                        num=max(alpha_beta_dist/float(precision), 2))
```

---

`np.linspace` will return both endpoints (by default) unless `num` is less than 2:

```
In [23]: np.linspace(0, 1, num=0)
Out[23]: array([], dtype=float64)

In [24]: np.linspace(0, 1, num=1)
Out[24]: array([ 0.])

In [25]: np.linspace(0, 1, num=2)
Out[25]: array([ 0.,  1.])
```

Comment: I think for my situation `traversal = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0,num=np.ceil(alpha_beta_dist/float(precision))` would be even better

Comment: Including `np.ceil` to make `num` an integer is sensible, but if you don't use `max(..., 2)` I don't see how your solution has any relation to mine.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Well considering the fact that in my scenario precision is always smaller than 1.0 and in addition I also consider that I have to get only the beginning if the alpha_beta_dist=0 therefore getting 2 for that would count one point twice.

Comment: I think I should make it like `max(1,np.ceil(alpha_beta_dist/float(precision))`. This takes care of that scenario